# How do I start/stop JBoss on system startup on Mac Lion?

Tags: jboss, osx-lion

I'm using Mac Lion (10.7.3) and I just downloaded JBoss 7.1.0.  I would like JBoss to run when I start my machine.  So I created this directory

```
/Library/StartupItems/JBoss/
```

and then created a file named "JBoss" within the above directory containing ...

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.common

StartService () 
{
    ConsoleMessage "Starting JBoss"
    $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh 
}

StopService () 
{
    ConsoleMessage "Stopping JBoss"
    # Don't know what to put here.  
}

RunService "$1"
```

What, if anything, do I need to put in the "StopService" clause to stop JBoss?  Also, is this the right way to go about running JBoss in the background when I start my machine?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

Looking in the README.txt it states this:

> If the server is running in a background process, the server can be stopped using the JBoss CLI:
>
> JBOSS_HOME>/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:shutdown